# How To Get the ActiveX Active Control from a Worksheet in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, activex, vba

I have a spreadsheet with some ActiveX controls like combo boxes, text boxes, etc... on the Change event of each control there's function that receives the ActiveSheet as parameter. this funtion is in the MainModule. what I need is to get the active control from this ActiveSheet having in mind that this control is an ActiveX control.

for instance, everytime I do changes in the combo boxes, text boxes, etc... I call this function and, through the ActiveSheet (passed as parameter) I can know if I changed a combo box or a text box or a list box, etc...

thanks in advance.

Comment: pass the control name as an argument to the function

Comment: I'm trying to avoid this. Isn't there a way to identify the active control into the ActiveSheet?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but passing the name is so easy .. why are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Do you need to pass the worksheet to the function or can you just pass a string that tells the function the type of control that called it? Edit: as @ScottHoltzman said.....I should have refreshed

Comment: I need to pass the worksheet (ActiveSheet). I'm trying to do this way because I need to identify the active control in different functions.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a activeX checkbox control and name it "chkboxFoo" via Properties Window.

```
Dim IsFooChecked As Boolean : IsFooChecked = False
IsFooChecked = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("chkboxFoo").Object.Value
If IsFooChecked Then
    MsgBox "BarMsg! You made it."
Else
    MsgBox "Try to check the checkbox then execute the program. " & _
           "You shall see a msgbox says BarMsg."
```

Reference: http://blogs.infoextract.in/worksheet-controls-automation-using-vba/